Finding derivative with two functions sharing the same independent variable
Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ , provided that $x=f(t)$, $y=g(t)$, $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable, and $y$ is also a differentiable function of $x$, and $f$ is bijective.
already have:
$(h\circ i)'=(h'\circ i)\cdot i'\quad(1)$ chain rule
$(h^{-1})'=1/(h'\circ h^{-1})\quad (2)$ differentiation of inverse function
my steps:
$\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}=(g\circ f^{-1})'$
$\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}=(g'\circ f^{-1})\cdot(f^{-1})'\quad$ applying$(1)$
$\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}=(g'\circ f^{-1})/(f'\circ f^{-1})\quad$ applying$(2)$
and$(g'\circ f^{-1})/(f'\circ f^{-1})$is not equal to$( g'/f')$,which is the correct answer

Don't use $f,g$ when you are talking about general functions when you already have two specific functions by that name. Here, $f\circ g$ doesn't make any sense given the specific $f,g$ of the question.

Please use descriptive titles.

What @ThomasAndrews meant was: when you want to apply rules (1) and (2) to $(g\circ f^{-1})$ (as you have to) it is not a very good idea to formulate those rules with $g$ replaced by $f$ and $f^{-1}$ replaced by $g,.$ Introduce other function names to disentangle this notation. Writing $h=f^{-1}$ and chain rule on $(g\circ h)$ is the least expensive.

Better. The rule (2) of which you don't know the name is "differentiation of the inverse function". Secondly: your title should be descriptive, as @CameronWilliams pointed out already.


We need $y$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and to be a function of $x\,.$

As given however, $y$ is a function of $t\,:$ $y=g(t)\,.$ (This will inevitably
lead to a slight abuse of notation.)

What we do is to look at $(g\circ f^{-1})(x)$ which is the equivalent of $y$ but written as a function of $x\,.$

As you have shown by the chain rule and by differentiating the inverse function:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(g\circ f^{-1})(x)=\frac{(g'\circ f^{-1})(x)}{(f'\circ f^{-1})(x)}
$$

The slight abuse of notation I mentioned is to consider this being $\frac{dy}{dx}\,.$

Who says that the correct answer is $\frac{g'}{f'}\,?$ This does not make sense because that is a function of $t\,.$



@joggingrat The "correct answer" is evaluated at $x=f(t)$.  $$\begin{align}((g'\circ f^{-1})/(f'\circ f^{-1})) ~(x) &= ((g'/f')\circ f^{-1})~(x)\[1ex] &= (g'/f')~(t)& \text{when }x:=f(t)\end{align}$$

@GrahamKemp that is a nice way of clarifying it. Should be done more in thermodynamics.

You are correct.  They've merely evaluated their "correct answer" at $x=f(t)$ rather than leaving it as a function of $x$.
Here's another approach.
$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x} & =\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d t}\dfrac{\mathrm d t}{\mathrm d x}&&\text{Chain Rule}\\ &= g'(t)\cdot (1/f'(t))&&\tfrac{\mathrm d t}{\mathrm d x}=1/\tfrac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t}\\ &= (g'/f')\,(t)\\ &= (g'/f')\circ f^{-1}\,(x)\\&= ((g'\circ f^{-1})/(f'\circ f^{-1}))\,(x)\end{align}$$
